# Missing Libraries When Trying to Use GPU with Tensorflow

Tags: nvidia, cuda, gpu, libraries, tensorflow

I am trying to use GPU with Tensorflow, so I installed CUDA 10.1, CUNN 7.6, TensorRT 6,  and Tensorflow-GPU 2.1.0. But when I import tensorflow to check if it can detect the gpu. it gives me the following error

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
2020-04-22 14:44:14.473830: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64
2020-04-22 14:44:14.473880: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.6'; dlerror: libnvinfer_plugin.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64
2020-04-22 14:44:14.473887: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:30] Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly.
```

Can you tell me how can I get the missing libraries please?

Thank you 
Hadeel

Comment: You have totally messed up your PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  All the system areas are missing in PATH, and you have multiple copies of the CUDA bin and lib64.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Ubuntu 19.10 (and likely other versions):

WARNING: This might hose your NVIDIA graphics driver so back steps to boot via backup disk, ZFS snapshot, or whatever. You have been warned.

I was able to boot into a graphical version, but OpenGL was broken. Directions on how I restored this are below.

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1810/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1810_10.1.168-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1810_10.1.168-1_amd64.deb
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1810/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt update
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1804_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1804_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt update

sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends \
    cuda-10-1 \
    libcudnn7=7.6.4.38-1+cuda10.1  \
    libcudnn7-dev=7.6.4.38-1+cuda10.1

    # Install TensorRT. Requires that libcudnn7 is installed above.
sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends  
    libnvinfer6=6.0.1-1+cuda10.1 \
    libnvinfer-dev=6.0.1-1+cuda10.1 \
    libnvinfer-plugin6=6.0.1-1+cuda10.1
```

As I said above, I had to reinstall my NVIDIA graphics card drives:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt -u dist-upgrade
```

Then reboot and try both importing tensorflow as well as running an OpenGL application. Both should work if things went well.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by

1.First we need to find the location of "libnvinfer.so" files

```
sudo find . -iname libnvinfer.so*
```

I got result as follows:

> ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvinfer.so
> ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvinfer.so.6
> ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvinfer.so.7.2.1
> ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvinfer.so.7
> ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvinfer.so.6.0.1

Required files are in */usr/lib/x86-linux-gnu*

2. We need to add that path into $LD_LIBRARY_PATH (environment variable)

   echo "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" >> ~/.bashrc

   source ~/.bashrc